# any way to detect ctrl + click in javascript for osx browsers? no jQuery

Tags: javascript, events, click, mouse

using vanilla js. Any way to grab the "right-click" (option-click) from OSX?

```
function clickey(e)
{
  if(event.button==2 || /*how you'd do it in Java=)*/ e.getButton() == MouseButton.BUTTON3 )    
...    
}
```

but in js, how do eeet?

Comment: would i just have to pickup the keycode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to listen to the `contextmenu` event. This is triggered when the context menu should be shown. So either if the  *right* mouse butten or or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + *mouse*.

If it is not supported then you can try to check the `mousedown` event where `button` is `2`  and `ctrlKey` is `true` if it is triggered by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + *mouse*

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu",function(event){

});
```

**OR** (depending on what the browser supports)

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown",function(event){
    if( event.ctrlKey || event.button == 2 ) {
    }
});
```

**edit:** removed the `which` info

Answer (score 3):

I'm not experienced with OSX, but the [Mouse Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent) have the option to check the modifier keys. So something along these lines should work:

```
DOMElement.addEventListener("click",function(event){
   // either check directly the button
   if (event.button == 2){}
   // or
   if (event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey){
       // do stuff
   }  
});
```