# Edge browser: Prevent Ctrl + leftclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-edge

Is there a way to prevent the default behaviour of the Microsoft Edge browser, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `Left click` on a link?

Edge is opening the link in a new tab, but I want to have my own event for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `Left click`.

Comment: This is a common convention across browsers, at the browser level. Why would you want to change the way in which this convention works on [your site], thus potentially confusing the user?

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a `click` event handler to your links.
Then, in a handler, you can do `e.preventDefault()` in order to prevent default browser action. `e.ctrlKey` will tell you if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button is clicked.

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey === true)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your custom actions
  }
});
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zjjqf188/5/).

Since you have defined a `jquery` tag, I have used this. Of course, it can be easily done in vanilla JS.

Comment: This doesn't work in OSX, where ctrl-click [opens a context menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725824/any-way-to-detect-ctrl-click-in-javascript-for-osx-browsers-no-jquery)

Comment: @joews The OP wants it to work in Microsoft Edge browser, which is not available for OS X.

Comment: SO isn't just for the OP - the comment will be useful for other people who come across this question.

Comment: I tested both your code and your jsFiddle, both doesn´t work with the Edge browser (but it does work in Firefox).

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, no, the link is just opened in a new tab. Nothing else happens.