# Using d3-3d with pan & zoom while retaining rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the [d3-3d plugin](https://github.com/Niekes/d3-3d) to graph 3d bar charts, but I'd like to add the pan & zoom functionality while keeping the rotation. Just adding in `d3.zoom()` seems to conflict with the `d3.drag()` behavior - it appears to be random which one takes precedence and adds a lot of "jitter".

```js
var origin = [100, 85], scale = 5, j = 10, cubesData = [];
var alpha = 0, beta = 0, startAngle = Math.PI/6;

var svg = d3.select('svg')
  .call(d3.drag()
  .on('drag', dragged)
  .on('start', dragStart)
  .on('end', dragEnd))
  .append('g');

var color  = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
var cubesGroup = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'cubes');
var mx, my, mouseX, mouseY;

var cubes3D = d3._3d()
    .shape('CUBE')
    .x(function(d){ return d.x; })
    .y(function(d){ return d.y; })
    .z(function(d){ return d.z; })
    .rotateY( startAngle)
    .rotateX(-startAngle)
    .origin(origin)
    .scale(scale);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 40])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

cubesGroup.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  cubesGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);

}   

function processData(data, tt){

    /* --------- CUBES ---------*/

    var cubes = cubesGroup.selectAll('g.cube')
       .data(data, function(d){ return d.id });

    var ce = cubes
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'cube')
      .attr('fill', function(d){ return color(d.id); })
      .attr('stroke', function(d){
         return d3.color(color(d.id)).darker(2);
      })
      .merge(cubes)
      .sort(cubes3D.sort);

        cubes.exit().remove();

        /* --------- FACES ---------*/

        var faces = cubes.merge(ce)
          .selectAll('path.face')
          .data(function(d){ return d.faces; },
            function(d){ return d.face; }
          );

        faces.enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('class', 'face')
            .attr('fill-opacity', 0.95)
            .classed('_3d', true)
            .merge(faces)
            .transition().duration(tt)
            .attr('d', cubes3D.draw);

        faces.exit().remove();

        /* --------- TEXT ---------*/

        var texts = cubes.merge(ce)
          .selectAll('text.text').data(function(d){
        var _t = d.faces.filter(function(d){
            return d.face === 'top';
        });

        return [{height: d.height, centroid: _t[0].centroid}];
    });

    texts.enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'text')
      .attr('dy', '-.7em')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('font-family', 'sans-serif')
      .attr('font-weight', 'bolder')
      .attr('x', function(d){
        return origin[0] + scale * d.centroid.x
      })
      .attr('y', function(d){
        return origin[1] + scale * d.centroid.y
      })
      .classed('_3d', true)
      .merge(texts)
      .transition().duration(tt)
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .attr('stroke', 'none')
      .attr('x', function(d){
        return origin[0] + scale * d.centroid.x
      })
      .attr('y', function(d){
        return origin[1] + scale * d.centroid.y
      })
      .tween('text', function(d){
        var that = d3.select(this);
        var i = d3.interpolateNumber(+that.text(), Math.abs(d.height));
        return function(t){
          that.text(i(t).toFixed(1));
        };
      });

    texts.exit().remove();

    /* --------- SORT TEXT & FACES ---------*/
    ce.selectAll('._3d').sort(d3._3d().sort);
}

function init(){
    cubesData = [];
    var cnt = 0;
    for(var z = -j/2; z <= j/2; z = z + 5){
        for(var x = -j; x <= j; x = x + 5){
            var h = d3.randomUniform(-2, -7)();
            var _cube = makeCube(h, x, z);
            _cube.id = 'cube_' + cnt++;
            _cube.height = h;
            cubesData.push(_cube);
        }
    }
    processData(cubes3D(cubesData), 1000);
}

function dragStart(){
    mx = d3.event.x;
    my = d3.event.y;
}

function dragged(){
    mouseX = mouseX || 0;
    mouseY = mouseY || 0;
    beta   = (d3.event.x - mx + mouseX) * Math.PI / 230 ;
    alpha  = (d3.event.y - my + mouseY) * Math.PI / 230  * (-1);
    processData(cubes3D.rotateY(beta + startAngle)
      .rotateX(alpha - startAngle)(cubesData), 0);
}

function dragEnd(){
    mouseX = d3.event.x - mx + mouseX;
    mouseY = d3.event.y - my + mouseY;
}

function makeCube(h, x, z){
    return [
        {x: x - 1, y: h, z: z + 1}, // FRONT TOP LEFT
        {x: x - 1, y: 0, z: z + 1}, // FRONT BOTTOM LEFT
        {x: x + 1, y: 0, z: z + 1}, // FRONT BOTTOM RIGHT
        {x: x + 1, y: h, z: z + 1}, // FRONT TOP RIGHT
        {x: x - 1, y: h, z: z - 1}, // BACK  TOP LEFT
        {x: x - 1, y: 0, z: z - 1}, // BACK  BOTTOM LEFT
        {x: x + 1, y: 0, z: z - 1}, // BACK  BOTTOM RIGHT
        {x: x + 1, y: h, z: z - 1}, // BACK  TOP RIGHT
    ];
}

d3.selectAll('button').on('click', init);

init();
```

```css
button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-3d/build/d3-3d.min.js"></script>
<body>
<svg width="200" height="175"></svg>
</body>
```

I'd like to mimic the behavior from [vis.js](http://visjs.org/examples/graph3d/playground/index.html).

(1) `Ctrl+drag` would translate the origin (two finger drag on mobile)

(2) `drag` would rotate (one finger drag on mobile)

(3) `zoom` would scale (two finger pinch on mobile)

How do I stop the propagation and only handle these events specifically?

Edit: It appears that the [bar chart example](https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/613d43d39372f99ae2dcea14f0f90617) has a `scale()` and `origin()` that can be set - but I would prefer to work with `transforms` for speed and efficiency of the update (as opposed to re-drawing).

Comment: In case you want the bar charts to be actually used for their purpose, and not only have them for decoration, you might want to consider using multiple 2D bar charts instead...

Comment: 3D charts are usually a bad practice and an antipattern. It's ugly and not UX friendly.

Comment: @rm4 - thanks, I think your comment is useful for others who may see the question later, but in this instance it's scientific modeling in 3D space. The bar chart is to emphasize discreteness vs a continuous random variable and is used in literature quite often.

Comment: It seems (after several tries) you can not capture crtl+click anymore. See ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438932 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725824 . Regarding the jitter that disappears 'outside' the bars so your translate interferes with the rotate d3-3d. Maybe remove the transforms?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the type of event using `d3.event.sourceEvent`. In the code you shared, the dragging anywhere in the white space will rotate and dragging on the bars will move.

With `d3.event.sourceEvent` you can check whether the `ctrl` key is pressed and move/rotate accordingly. You don't even need the `drag` function for your `svg`. It can be handled using the `zoom` functions alone.

Here's the fiddle:

```js
var origin = [100, 85],
  scale = 5,
  j = 10,
  cubesData = [];
var alpha = 0,
  beta = 0,
  startAngle = Math.PI / 6;
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 40])
  .on("zoom", zoomed)
  .on('start', zoomStart)
  .on('end', zoomEnd);
var svg = d3.select('svg').call(zoom)
  .append('g');

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
var cubesGroup = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'cubes').attr('transform', 'translate(0,0) scale(1)');
var mx, my, mouseX, mouseY;

var cubes3D = d3._3d()
  .shape('CUBE')
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .z(function(d) {
    return d.z;
  })
  .rotateY(startAngle)
  .rotateX(-startAngle)
  .origin(origin)
  .scale(scale);

function zoomStart() {
  mx = d3.event.sourceEvent.x;
  my = d3.event.sourceEvent.y;
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent !== null && d3.event.sourceEvent.type == 'mousemove' && d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey == true) {
    cubesGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }
}

function zoomEnd() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent == null) return;
  mouseX = d3.event.sourceEvent.x - mx + mouseX
  mouseY = d3.event.sourceEvent.y - my + mouseY
}

function zoomed(d) {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent == null) return;

  if (d3.event.sourceEvent !== null && d3.event.sourceEvent.type == 'wheel') {
    cubesGroup.attr("transform", "scale(" + d3.event.transform['k'] + ")");
  } else if (d3.event.sourceEvent !== null && d3.event.sourceEvent.type == 'mousemove' && d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey == true) {
    cubesGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform['x'] + "," + d3.event.transform['y'] + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform['k'] + ")");
  } else if (d3.event.sourceEvent !== null && d3.event.sourceEvent.type == 'mousemove' && d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey == false) {
    mouseX = mouseX || 0;
    mouseY = mouseY || 0;
    beta = (d3.event.sourceEvent.x - mx + mouseX) * Math.PI / 230;
    alpha = (d3.event.sourceEvent.y - my + mouseY) * Math.PI / 230 * (-1);
    processData(cubes3D.rotateY(beta + startAngle)
      .rotateX(alpha - startAngle)(cubesData), 0);

  };
}

function processData(data, tt) {

  /* --------- CUBES ---------*/

  var cubes = cubesGroup.selectAll('g.cube')
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.id
    });

  var ce = cubes
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'cube')
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
      return color(d.id);
    })
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
      return d3.color(color(d.id)).darker(2);
    })
    .merge(cubes)
    .sort(cubes3D.sort);

  cubes.exit().remove();

  /* --------- FACES ---------*/

  var faces = cubes.merge(ce)
    .selectAll('path.face')
    .data(function(d) {
        return d.faces;
      },
      function(d) {
        return d.face;
      }
    );

  faces.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'face')
    .attr('fill-opacity', 0.95)
    .classed('_3d', true)
    .merge(faces)
    .transition().duration(tt)
    .attr('d', cubes3D.draw);

  faces.exit().remove();

  /* --------- TEXT ---------*/

  var texts = cubes.merge(ce)
    .selectAll('text.text').data(function(d) {
      var _t = d.faces.filter(function(d) {
        return d.face === 'top';
      });

      return [{
        height: d.height,
        centroid: _t[0].centroid
      }];
    });

  texts.enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'text')
    .attr('dy', '-.7em')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('font-family', 'sans-serif')
    .attr('font-weight', 'bolder')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return origin[0] + scale * d.centroid.x
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return origin[1] + scale * d.centroid.y
    })
    .classed('_3d', true)
    .merge(texts)
    .transition().duration(tt)
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .attr('stroke', 'none')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return origin[0] + scale * d.centroid.x
    })
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return origin[1] + scale * d.centroid.y
    })
    .tween('text', function(d) {
      var that = d3.select(this);
      var i = d3.interpolateNumber(+that.text(), Math.abs(d.height));
      return function(t) {
        that.text(i(t).toFixed(1));
      };
    });

  texts.exit().remove();

  /* --------- SORT TEXT & FACES ---------*/
  ce.selectAll('._3d').sort(d3._3d().sort);
}

function init() {
  cubesData = [];
  var cnt = 0;
  for (var z = -j / 2; z <= j / 2; z = z + 5) {
    for (var x = -j; x <= j; x = x + 5) {
      var h = d3.randomUniform(-2, -7)();
      var _cube = makeCube(h, x, z);
      _cube.id = 'cube_' + cnt++;
      _cube.height = h;
      cubesData.push(_cube);
    }
  }
  processData(cubes3D(cubesData), 1000);
}

function dragStart() {
  console.log('dragStart')
  mx = d3.event.x;
  my = d3.event.y;
}

function dragged() {
  console.log('dragged')
  mouseX = mouseX || 0;
  mouseY = mouseY || 0;
  beta = (d3.event.x - mx + mouseX) * Math.PI / 230;
  alpha = (d3.event.y - my + mouseY) * Math.PI / 230 * (-1);
  processData(cubes3D.rotateY(beta + startAngle)
    .rotateX(alpha - startAngle)(cubesData), 0);
}

function dragEnd() {
  console.log('dragend')
  mouseX = d3.event.x - mx + mouseX;
  mouseY = d3.event.y - my + mouseY;
}

function makeCube(h, x, z) {
  return [{
      x: x - 1,
      y: h,
      z: z + 1
    }, // FRONT TOP LEFT
    {
      x: x - 1,
      y: 0,
      z: z + 1
    }, // FRONT BOTTOM LEFT
    {
      x: x + 1,
      y: 0,
      z: z + 1
    }, // FRONT BOTTOM RIGHT
    {
      x: x + 1,
      y: h,
      z: z + 1
    }, // FRONT TOP RIGHT
    {
      x: x - 1,
      y: h,
      z: z - 1
    }, // BACK  TOP LEFT
    {
      x: x - 1,
      y: 0,
      z: z - 1
    }, // BACK  BOTTOM LEFT
    {
      x: x + 1,
      y: 0,
      z: z - 1
    }, // BACK  BOTTOM RIGHT
    {
      x: x + 1,
      y: h,
      z: z - 1
    }, // BACK  TOP RIGHT
  ];
}

d3.selectAll('button').on('click', init);

init();
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-3d/build/d3-3d.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
</body>
```

On [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aditya_kk29/cqvvLfs7/)